# what is the difference between Eloquent and database authentication drivers in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, authentication

In laravel, inside the `config/auth.php`

we have this by default

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

**My question is** what is the difference between these two drivers?
if I change the driver to `database` does that mean i can't use eloquent anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference: `eloquent` uses an ORM abstraction over a table, while `database` uses direct SQL queries. If you intend to have a custom Auth class, the ORM abstraction is easier to extend. If you (just have tables and you don't intend to extend your Auth layer) or (you don't use Eloquent for anything else), then database is a good choice.

The technical reason for this difference is subtle, and perhaps surprising: *a Laravel-based application need not use the Eloquent ORM*. In that usage, the application might still want to use the Laravel-provided Authentication facade, so Laravel needs a different way of storing and retrieving the authentication data: hence the database driver.

From the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication):

> If your application is not using Eloquent, you may use the database authentication driver which uses the Laravel query builder.

Most Laravel-based applications use Eloquent, so the default is to use the Eloquent Auth class. If you change the driver to `database`, you can still use Eloquent in your app, though I can't imagine a use case for this combination.

Comment: can you add your last comment to the answer? so i can make this answered

Comment: "though I can't imagine a use case for this combination". I have an example use case specifically like that. I have two Laravel projects that both authenticate against the same users table in the same database, however on one of the projects User model is stored in App\User and in another  it's App\Models\User, if I use eloquent provider, the authentication fails due to differences of where the model is stored, thus setting it to "database" solves this issue.